# Retry timeout CURL

Tags: php, curl

What is better approach for retry curl request if there is a timeout?

I have came up with this solution using evil `GOTO`

```
retry:

$result = curlPost($ch, "something.php", $cookie, http_build_query($arg));

if (curl_errno($ch) == 28) {
    goto retry;
}

// Do something
```

In the `curlPost()` function, there is

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
```

Comment: Use loop and attempts counter

Comment: @Phantom I will have multiple CURL request in a script, to do loop for each curl request maybe a bit too much? If there is a timeout in any curl requests I would like to start again from the top.

Comment: Why are you using `goto`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retry curl request if it times out in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17903660/retry-curl-request-if-it-times-out-in-php)

Comment: @user1246800 what you have above is a loop. you could add an attempt counter to it as Phantom suggests so that it won't just sit and needlessly attempt the curl request if there is some network issue or something, but dont fool yourself in thinking that using goto somehow makes this different than a loop.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a do-while loop.

```
$count = 0;
$max_tries = 5;
$success = true;
do {
    $result = curlPost($ch, "something.php", $cookie, http_build_query($arg));
    $count++;
    if($count >= $max_tries) {
        $success = false;
        break;
    }
}
while(curl_errno($ch) == 28);

if($success == false) {
    // If it got here it tried 5 times and still didn't get a result.
    // More code here for what you want to do...
}
```

Comment: Note: `$success = false`; is an unreachable statement

Comment: @snowdragon : re-ordered! :-)

Comment: Actually, also if the fifth retry is successful, this will say it's failed. :-)